# Lyx problem with wrap figure

Tags: lyx, wrapfigure

I am writing a report in Lyx. I always have problem with wrap figure. I have a lot of white space under it, like on figure and don't know how to solve. In wrap figure settings I put:
Placement: Outer (default)
Width: 40 column width %
not checked overhang and line span.
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What about check line span, set some value like "20" and according to the result, reduce or enlarge that value?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know there was a gui for wrapfig arguments!

The wrapping is based on counting lines (because `\parshape`), and the counting can be thrown off both by vertical space (as before *Primedba*) and by larger equations (those bigger than three lines of paragraph text). That's when you have to use the line-count argument.

Sorry it is hard to count (hypothetical ordinary) lines in such a situation! You could measure your image and divide that by the line spacing. Using wrapfig with the [verbose] option should report the line count, since it is easier to adjust a previous value than to count the whole size.

A trick is to temporarily put

```
Wrapping \arabic{WF@wrappedlines} lines.
```

after `\end{wrapfigure}`, and read the value from the output.